# How to send photos from iPhone to Windows PC without cable and Internet

Tags: ios, wifi, windows, photos, file-transfer

I am trying to send the pictures (and videos) I have to my Windows PC, but don't want to upload them to any cloud services. I cannot use USB because there is a problem with the socket. I can only charge the phone. The phone has internet connection and I can download apps.

An option is to start a server and connect via wifi, but how?

What are the free solutions for that? Or what can you suggest?

Comment: for file transfer you can use samba: SMB/CIFS file sharing on Windows, some file manager with samba option on iPhone (for example, FE by Skyjos). And what about Bluetooth?

Comment: @Andra yes, bluetooth is also fine

Comment: Good question @xiley71701, very interested for answers!

Comment: This could potentially be a duplicate of: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399362/any-free-way-to-transfer-pictures-from-an-iphone-x-to-any-other-pc-via-wifi/399363#399363

Comment: @Kevin Grabher, RE: "his could potentially be a duplicate of: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399362/any-free-way-to-transfer-pictures-from-an-iphone-x-to-any-other-pc-via-wifi/399363#399363" --  As this question was posted 3 month before the linked one, then technically that one is a duplicate of this one. However as the linked one has an accepted answer this one will probably become marked a duplicate of the linked one.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS app [GoodReader](https://www.goodreader.com/sharing-files-over-a-local-wifi-network) allows you to start a web server over wifi that shares GoodReader files (which can include photos). Your Windows PC should be able to connect using wifi and a web browser. GoodReader is a free download, but I don't know if this feature will be enabled without paying some $.

BTW, I have no connection with the developer. However I have used the app for many years.

Comment: Thank you. *"that shares GoodReader files"*, what do you mean by GoodReader files? On the PC side, will the download happen via the browser? Isn't there a more direct way, directly at a file layer, rather than in the browser?

Comment: I mean you share whatever files are imported into GoodReader. You can import photos into GoodReader (directly on the device). Yes you will need to use the web browser on the PC. If you want to do it at the file layer you will need a SMB server on the iOS device. However you will not have SMB browse access directly to the photos library. That isn't available as far as I know - at least not on a non jailbroken iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iOS app [PhotoSync](https://www.photosync-app.com/home.html) which will synchronise your photos with its "companion" app running on Mac or Windows. The only requirement is that both iPhone and Mac/Windows are on the same LAN.

So long as the companion app is running, you control photo transfers from the iPhone.

The iOS app is "free", but only transfers low res photos. This is sufficient to establish that it will work for you. You then need an in-app purchase to enable full functionality. The companion app is free.

I have used PhotoSync for many years.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone can connect to any SMB share via the Files App.

1. [Enable sharing for a folder in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-10-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf)
2. On the iPhone: Open the Files App
3. Tap the icon with the 3 dots in the top right corner
4. Tap "Connect to Server"
5. For the address use smb://x.x.x.x (where x.x.x.x is your computers IP address or network name) and enter the corresponding username and password for your PC user.

Then from the Photos App (as well as most other Apps) you can tap the Share icon and tap "Save to Files", where you can not select your PC as the destination.