# How to download any file to iPad from a cloud drive through the browser?

Tags: ipad, data-transfer, web-browser, icloud

Is there a way to download files from a cloud drive to the ipad through its browser?

I made a dummy text file and uploaded to a cloud drive with a public link,
https://tinyurl.com/6whmxito
and then accessed it through the iPad through both Chrome and Safari.
The link works, but I'm not able to download the text file (or any other file).

This download-via-browser was also confirmed successful in all other non-apple devices (PC, phone, etc.).
Is there a step missing?

Comment: A number of years ago I started using iCab for the iPhone because is explicitly allowed you to download files. However the Files.app can access files (upload/download, both!) on my Dropbox account. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Steve Chambers I looked for iCab in app store and it lists the app for a fee. However, I'm not sure if its worth paying for a very standard function that already exists for free on any other device (just want to be able to download any file). It is surprising that something like this isn't readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my findings, it appears that you simply can't download files with any default free browser.

The most practical way was to use VLC and transfer the file over WiFi from any other device that supports browser file downloads.
Steps that made it work were as follows: (https://techlog360.com/wireless-file-transfer-from-pc-to-ipad-iphone/)

1. Connect iPad to the same WiFi network as the other device.
2. Download the file with any other device that supports downloading from a browser.
3. On the iPad, install VLC.
4. Open VLC, on the Network settings, turn on "Sharing via WiFi".
5. On the device, open the browser and input the IP address that appeared in the step above.
6. Press the + button, select the files from the device, and upload the files.
7. The files are then located in "Files (Apple app) -> On My iPad".

Comment: Actually, like I said in my comment above, the (built-in) files.app in recent versions of iOS will connect to cloud storage like Dropbox (and others). And as the OP said, "...uploaded to a cloud drive with a public link." You can bypass creating a link and going through a browser and download it "directly" via the aforementioned files.app

Comment: Does that method involve having to use your login credentials for access? There's a reason to make a public link in that it would work for anyone / anywhere.

Comment: if you need to send a link to a file that is one use case. The use case I posit is for **YOU** to access files on your personal devices that you are already logged into. If other people need access to that file they *MAY* be able to access it via Safari and then File.app. I have a location in Files that is called *on my iPhone* perhaps Safari can download and would place those files there. You will need to do some investigation.